# Excel VBA String Evaluation

Tags: vba, excel

I'm wondering if it's possible to use some VBA to find defined patterns in a whole bunch of 5char strings? I've explored the "instr" function but I'm not sure if it will perform the task I require which is basically to find patterns in the string like the following;

```
ABABA
BCBCB
.....
EFEFE
```

Or any such pattern where the 1st char is the same as chars 3 & 5, and the 2nd char is the same as char 4.

Any help or direction would be gratefully received.

Kind regards

Jim

Comment: Please add an example of source text and an example of the expected result you want.

Comment: Will the pattern always be 1,3,5 and 2,4 like above or are you just looking for any pattern?

Comment: Hi @zedfoxus
Apologies if the question was vague. Source text would be a list of random 5 char strings consisting solely of letters. I just need some sort of flag to identify whether the pattern I'm looking for exists in each string.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the response Scott. Initially the pattern I'm looking for will be 1,3,5 and 2,4 however if there is a way of identifying other types of patterns then this would be extremely helpful also.

Again, in the first instance I'd just be looking for a flag on each string (each present in one Excel row) to say whether the 1,3,5 - 2,4 pattern is true or false.

Comment: Could you just not type in something like this in Excel? `=AND(MID(A1,1,1)=MID(A1,3,1), MID(A1,1,1)=MID(A1,5,1))`. That will return TRUE if first character is the same as 3rd and 5th. `=MID(A1,2,1)=MID(A1,4,1)` will return TRUE if 2nd and 4th characters match

Comment: @zedfoxus Jeez louise I can't believe I didn't think of that, long day! This would be a really simple way of doing it. I guess it would be nice to productionise the solution at some point, whereupon VBA might come in handy, but this meets my requirements for now. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I actually went for this in the end...[image: string pattern excel]

Embarrassingly simple, literally cannot believe I didn't consider this as an option first and instead just assumed it should be done in VBA. A valuable lesson!

Had to mod the formulae anyway because my initial pattern flag (1,3,5 & 2,4) evaluated to big fat FALSE across the board, so I decided to look for 1,3 & 2,4 with 5 being anything. As I mentioned in my comment to @zedfoxus this gets me to where I need to be right now but it would be great to use VBA to productionise this.
I'm going to review all your answers so thanks for taking the time to respond, I frickin' love this place!

PEACE!

Comment: See my edit for something that might help porductionise the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without VBA and it would still be fast enough:

```
=IF(AND(MID("ABABA",1,1)=MID("ABABA",3,1),MID("ABABA",2,1)=MID("ABABA",4,1),MID("ABABA",3,1)=MID("ABABA",5,1)),1,0)
```

just replace "ABABA" with corresponding cell address and that's it

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Like` operator:

```
Const testString = "ABABA"
Dim myChar1 As String, myChar2 As String

'// test 1/3/5
myChar1 = Mid(testString, 1, 1)
'// test2/4
myChar2 = Mid(testString, 2, 1)

If testString Like myChar1 & "[A-Z]" & myChar1 & "[A-Z]" & myChar1 Then
    MsgBox "Matches 1, 3 and 5"
ElseIf testString Like "[A-Z]" & myChar2 & "[A-Z]" & myChar 2 & "[A-Z]" Then
    Msgbox "Matches 2 and 4"
End If
```

---

Or use the `Mid()` function:

```
If Mid(testString, 1, 1) = Mid(testString, 3, 1) And _
   Mid(testString, 3, 1) = Mid(testString, 5, 1) And _
   Mid(testString, 1, 1) = Mid(testString, 5, 1) Then

    MsgBox "Matches 1, 3 and 5"

ElseIf Mid(testString, 2, 1) = Mid(testString, 4, 1) Then

    MsgBox "Matches 2 and 4"

End If
```

---

**OR** to check for both conditions:

```
Dim match1 As String, match2 As String
Const testString As String = "ABABA"

match1 = Left(testString, 1) & "[A-Z]" & Left(testString, 1) & "[A-Z]" & Left(testString, 1)

match2 = "[A-Z]" & Left(testString, 1) & "[A-Z]" & Left(testString, 1) & "[A-Z]"

If testString Like match1 Or testString Like match2 Then
    MsgBox "findwindow likes it when anything matches"
End If
```

Comment: Wow even called me out in the msgbox. I is special.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing my hat in the ring XD

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My turn:

```
Function findPattern(inputStr As String) As Variant()
Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Integer
arr = Split(inputStr)
ReDim arr2(UBound(arr)) As Variant
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If Left(arr(i), 1) = Mid(arr(i), 3, 1) And _
        Left(arr(i), 1) = Mid(arr(i), 5, 1) And _
        Mid(arr(i), 2, 1) = Mid(arr(i), 4, 1) Then

        arr2(i) = "True"
    Else
        arr2(i) = "False"
    End If
    findPattern = arr2
Next
End Function

Sub trying()

    Dim t As String
    t = "ABABA BCBCB IOITU"
    arr = findPattern(t) 'returns an array {True,True,False}

    For x = 0 To 2
    Debug.Print arr(x)
    Next
End Sub
```

This assumes that you have multiple words in each string.  It returns an array of true false.

Edit

To find it there are any patterns use this UDF:

```
Function findPattern(inputStr As String) As String
Dim i As Integer
For i = 5 To 1 Step -1
If Asc(Mid(inputStr, i, 1)) > 5 Then
    inputStr = Replace(inputStr, Mid(inputStr, i, 1), i)
End If
findPattern = inputStr
Next

End Function
```

It will return 12121 on "ABABA"

You can paste this in a module in the workbook then use it like a formula: `=findPattern("A1")`  Copy it down.  Then sort on the column, it will place all like patterns together with the most patternized (11111) to the least (12345).

Then you could also filter on this column for any pattern you desire.