# How can I convert these inelegant formulae into VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Good people of Stackland

I'm analysing strings comprised of 5 alpha chars which in their raw format look like this;

```
A2) BCDBE
A3) TLDPP
A4) FGGFC
A5) BBGBB
```

I need a way of evaluating each character to identify patterns within the strings themselves, eg repeating letters. I want to represent these patterns as follows, where the 1st letter is always given as "A", the 2nd "B"...;

```
A2) BCDBE --> ABCAD
A3) TLDPP --> ABCDD 
A4) FGGFC --> ABBAC 
A5) BBGBB --> AABAA
```

Now, I have achieved this with some pretty inelegant conditional formulae but had to do this to evaluate each character individually, as follows;

```
1) =IF(LEFT(A2,1)>0,"A")
2) =IF(MID(A2,2,1)=LEFT(A2,1),"A","B")
3) =IF(MID(A2,3,1)=LEFT(A2,1),"A",IF(MID(A2,3,1)=MID(A2,2,1),M2,CHAR(CODE(M2)+1)))
4) =IF(MID(A2,4,1)=LEFT(A2,1),"A",IF(MID(A2,4,1)=MID(A2,2,1),M2,IF(MID(A2,4,1)=MID(A2,3,1),N2,CHAR(MAX(CODE(L2:N2)+1)))))
5) =IF(MID(A2,5,1)=LEFT(A2,1),"A",IF(MID(A2,5,1)=MID(A2,2,1),M2,IF(MID(A2,5,1)=MID(A2,3,1),N2,IF(MID(A2,5,1)=MID(A2,4,1),O2,CHAR(MAX(CODE(L2:O2)+1))))))
```

Translated...

```
1) Call the first character "A"
2) If the 2nd character is the same as the same as the 1st call it "A", otherwise cause it "B"
3) If the 3rd character is the same as the 1st call it "A", if it's the same as the 2nd call it whatever the 2nd is, if not give it the value of the next letter, ie "C"
4) If the 4th character is the same as the 1st, call it "A", if it's the sames as the 2nd call it whatever the 2nd is, if it's the same as the 3rd call it whatever the 3rd is, if not then call it the next letter in the alphabet, ie "D"
5) If the 5th character is the same as the 1st, call it "A", if it's the same as the 2nd call it whatever the 2nd is, if it's the same as the 3rd call it whatever the 3rd is called, if it's the same as the 4th call it whatever the 4th is called, if not then call it the next letter in the alphabet, ie "E"
```

I'm doing this over 5 cols, one formula per col, and the concatenating the 5 results into one cell to get AABAA or whatever.

I just need to know if there's a nice, clean VBA solution to this.

Any ideas?

Comment: So the number function I gave you in my edit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958467/excel-vba-string-evaluation) won't work?  It is a function that you call from the worksheet.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner Thanks so much for responding. Yeah it did but I kinda messed it up with my complete incompetence and then thought I'd try my method. I should have responded to your original answer.

The mod you've pasted below, how would I add a trim function to that so it's only evaluating the first 5 chars? I've got some other extraneous stuff coming through which I want to omit.

Comment: That's okay, see my updated one below.

Comment: @ScottCraner Still evaluating beyond the 5 character, do I need to use Trim?

Comment: So you have more characters after the first five in the cell?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah that's right. I actually have, for example, ABCCE.xyz  for which your awesome solution is returning ABCCD.xyz but I don't need the ".xyz"

Comment: So you just want the first five returned?

Comment: @ScottCraner Excactly that

Comment: See edit, I fixed it.

Comment: @ScottCraner You;ve proven once again you're a credit to the Stack community. Really appreciate your time brother, and thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the a Function to do the letter instead of numbers:

```
Function findPattern(inputStr As String) As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Integer

t = 1
For i = 1 To 5 Step 1
    If Asc(Mid(inputStr, i, 1)) > 54 Then
        inputStr = Replace(inputStr, Mid(inputStr, i, 1), t)
        t = t + 1
    End If
Next i
For i = 1 To 5
    inputStr = Replace(inputStr, i, Chr(i + 64))
Next i

findPattern = inputStr


End Function
```

Put it in a module attached to the workbook, and you can call it thus:

```
=findPattern(A2)
```

Driectly from the worksheet where A2 is the cell you want tested.

Or from vba:

```
Sub test()
    Dim str as string
    str = findPattern(Range("A2").value)
    debug.print str
End Sub
```

Edit: By your Comment I assume you have more than just the first 5 characters that you want left original.  If that is the case use this:

```
Function findPattern(Str As String) As String
Dim inputStr As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Integer

inputStr = Left(Str, 5)

t = 1
For i = 1 To 5 Step 1

If Asc(Mid(inputStr, i, 1)) > 54 Then
    inputStr = Replace(inputStr, Mid(inputStr, i, 1), t)
    t = t + 1
End If
Next i
For i = 1 To 5
    inputStr = Replace(inputStr, i, Chr(i + 64))
Next i
'This is the return line.  As is it will only return 5 characters.
'If you want the whole string with only the first five as the pattern
'Remove the single quote in the middle of the string.
findPattern = inputStr '& Mid(Str, 6, (Len(Str)))


End Function
```

Comment: @jimiclapton  See the edit, I made it only do the first five characters, and ignore anything after the first five.

Comment: @jimiclapton  See New edit, I have commented out the last part of the return variable.  It now will only return the first five character pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an easy approach:

```
's is the input string
dim pos, c, s_new, s_old
pos = 1 : c = 49
s_new = mid(s, 1, 5) ' take only first five characters
do while pos <= 5
    s_old = s_new
    s_new = replace(s_new, mid(s, pos, 1), chr(c))
    if s_new <> s_old then c = c + 1
loop

s_new = replace(s_new, "1", "A")
s_new = replace(s_new, "2", "B")
s_new = replace(s_new, "3", "C")
s_new = replace(s_new, "4", "D")
s_new = replace(s_new, "5", "E")
```

'm assuming that you don't have any numeric characters in your input.

Comment: This is a great method, but it does not output what the OP is asking, for example the first one "BCDBE", the OP wants "ABCAD" and yours returns "ABCAE".  Mine did the same, I needed to put in a separate counter that increased only when it found something to replace.

Answer (score 0):

This has a certain elegance:

```
Function Pattern(r As Range)
    Dim c&, i&, a
    Const FORMULA = "iferror(find(mid(~,{2,3,4,5},1),left(~,{1,2,3,4})),)"
    a = Evaluate(Replace(FORMULA, "~", r.Address))
    c = 1: Pattern = "A"
    For i = 1 To 4
        If a(i) = 0 Then c = c + 1: a(i) = c
        Pattern = Pattern & Chr$(64 + a(i))
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this for a while (it's handy for cryptograms), so I'll post it:

```
Function Pattern(ByVal sInp As String) As String
  ' shg 2012

  ' Returns the pattern of a string as a string of the same length
  ' First unique letter and all repeats is a, second is b, …
  ' E.g., Pattern("mississippi") returns "abccbccbddb"

  Dim iChr          As Long     ' character index to sInp & Pattern
  Dim sChr          As String   ' character in sInp
  Dim iPos          As Long     ' position of first appearance of sChr in sInp

  sInp = LCase(Trim(sInp))
  If Len(sInp) Then
    sChr = Chr(64)
    Pattern = sInp

    For iChr = 1 To Len(sInp)
      iPos = InStr(sInp, Mid(sInp, iChr, 1))
      If iPos = iChr Then  ' it's new
        sChr = Chr(Asc(sChr) + 1)
        Mid(Pattern, iChr) = sChr
      Else
        Mid(Pattern, iChr) = Mid(Pattern, iPos, 1)
      End If
    Next iChr
  End If
End Function
```